# How can I draw a water wave in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

This picture is taken from the game Cut the Rope:

[image]

I'm trying to recreate the wave.

This is what I have so far, I used `Distort > Wave`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the effect you are looking for is similar with [this tutorial from adobetutorialz.](http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/2999/1/Cool-abstract-background) Try changing some values and such along the way to mimic what you need. Hope that helps.