# by which graphic softwares this picture was created?

Tags: software-recommendation

[image: I wanna know this picture was created By which software , anybody knows?]
by which softwares this picture was created? any guess
by which software this water is drawn?

Comment: Hi Nastaran. Is this question different from your other one http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21855/how-can-i-draw-a-water-wave-in-photoshop?

Comment: @Yisela yes it was different

Comment: @Dominic yes you are right ,but answer to this question  even base on opinions can help me ,

Comment: @Dominic yes you're right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, probably Adobe Illustrator/Photoshop... Although there is no way to tell for sure.

Here's some tutorials/examples of things done in illustrator: http://www.creativebloq.com/digital-art/illustrator-tutorials-1232697

http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing/create-a-weather-app-design-for-ios-in-adobe-illustrator/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at video (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHuPTEJ9aRc), What I see are two textures: a foreground wave moving left to right, and a background wave moving right to left.

Each "wave" is a ^ shape which is tiled so that placing two copies side-by side shows no seam. They both have a lot of transparency.

The tiles were made using Photoshop probably. The animation itself is probably generated dynamically by the game software.

The lighting effects are done separately and do not appear to respond to the waves themselves they look like 2-3 looped animations which are duplicated and/or shifted randomly side to side and in time sequence.

Comment: my question isn't for animation becuase it will be done by Engins , only for drawing same this picture , for drawing these textures (you said) by which software they are drawn (in this picture you can feel the water+ texture for water like this)